# In which situations would you use either "Toilette", "Klo", "WC" or "Bad"?

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Inspired by [this question on the English StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/toilet-lavatory-or-loo-what-is-correct-for-polite-society) sister site, I'm asking the following question.

Which of the following synonyms is suitable for different situations (formal, colloquial, ...)? Is there a difference at all?

- Toilette
- Klo
- WC
- Bad

Are there other words for *bathroom* I could use? Are there regional differences?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a restaurant you'll only find `WC` or  `Toilette` on doors and signs. In an apartment/residence, you will ask for `Bad`, `WC` or `Toilette`. You will never ask a waiter in a restaurant about `das Bad`.

The word `Klo` is only used in very casual situations. `Scheißhaus` is very vulgar. Casual and funny is `die Keramik-Abteilung`, but you should never use this term in a hardware store, they may have a ceramic department for real.

Comment: Ha, I had never heard *Keramik-Abteilung* before! :)

Comment: +1 for the warning about when not to use *Keramikabteilung*.

Comment: You might also hear *Lokus* some times.

Comment: "Wo befinden sich ihre sanitären Einrichtungen?" is another formal way to inquire about the location of the toilets. Another casual word for loo is "Bedürfnissverrichtungsanstalt", which mimics the naming style of bureaucratic offices. It means "the public-law institution for the fullfillment of sanitary urges".

Answer (score 13):

In a very formal situation we may not wish to refer to the precise location but may rather ask

> *"Wo kann ich mir bitte die Hände waschen?"*

assuming that this is also the place your needs are going to be relieved. Still in a formal context asking for *"Toilette"* like in

> *"Entschuldigen Sie bitte, wo sind hier die Toiletten?"*

is perfectly fine.

In a more casual setting we could also use

> *"Wo geht es hier für kleine Jungs/Mädchen?"*
>   *"Wo ist denn hier das WC?"*

The use of *"Klo"* is recommended only in a very relaxed or familiary setting.

*"Badezimmer"* or *"Bad"* is not genererally used in this context, mostly because these rooms used to be, and still are separate.

Comment: "Badezimmer" or "Bad" is associated with a "complete" bathroom, including a shower, a toilet and/or a bathtub.

Comment: Generally agree, though I think "WC" could be used in a formal context as well, since that's what's often written at the doors/signs. In Schleswig-Holstein, on the other hand, *Schiethus* may be perfectly fine ;)

Comment: In Eastfrisia too ;-) (near the North-Sea)

Comment: Why 'für **kleine** Jungs'? It doesn't depend on the size.

Comment: "für kleine Jungs" is just an idiom to refer to the toilet.  I also use it, even though at 1m90 I'm definitely not "klein".

Comment: It seems English has the same idiom, "little boys' room". http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/toilet-lavatory-or-loo-for-polite-society/37179#37179

Comment: Beware that asking for "Hände waschen" can give unexpected results like: "Do it just here in the kitchen sink".

Comment: @Ingo: In a setting where you don't want to ask for the *Toilette* nobody will dare to show you the kitchen sink. But if somebody does you will be safe to ask this person for the *Klo* ;)

Comment: Takkat - not everybody knows of those more subtle cultural things, and this could lead to taking the question at face value. I think an American can and should learn that it is OK to ask for the toilet in german.

Answer (score 4):

```
* Toilette
* Klo
* WC
* Bad
```

Klo is short for Klosett, which is, if cleaned with water, a water closet, hence WC. So if it hasn't a water flushing, I wouldn't call it 'WC', but 'Klo' or 'Toilette'. All 3 words are used to describe the furniture as well as the room.

A 'Bad' is the room where the 'Badewanne' is located, and in most households, the bathroom contains a closet, but it needn't, and in a restaurant, or a public building like a library or a shopping mall, there is normally no bath or shower in the room, so you don't ask for a 'Bad' there.

'Klo' is a bit simple, so you ask for Toilette or WC when talking to strangers. In the family, or with close friends, 'Klo' is alright.